# How to set gravity for each line in android textview?

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left, left-to-right

I have a String that contains English and Persian. I want if a line starts with Persian charachter then this line is displaied right to left in text view and if a line starts with English Character then this line is displaied left to right.

Note: I want to set gravity/direction for each line in text view.

How to implement it in android textview.

this is my textview xml code:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textDirection="rtl" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align textview according to the language selection (LEFT -RIGHT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728604/align-textview-according-to-the-language-selection-left-right)

Comment: @AmitVaghela I updated my tittle and explanation about my problem.

Comment: Can you split your text and show English and Persian text parts separately in own `TextViews`? It seems to be the easiest solution IMHO.

Comment: @Artjom I use this text view in recycle view, and i think this solution reduce recycle view perforamnce. what's your idea about this?

Comment: I would always prefere an easy solution and optimize it only if it is **significantly** affects the performance. In your case I don't think that using multiple TextViews will have noticeable performance drawback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute of TextView to align text Content.

Allign text to left in the layout

```
android:gravity="start"
```

Aliign text to right in the layout.

```
android:gravity="end"
```

Comment: I add my textview xml code. I want to set gravity for each line.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is *ANY_RTL* text direction to be added to your text view

```
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

And you will get a result like this:

[image]

Conside that it is an API17+ solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the gravity attribute.

Instead of left/right use start, that was added for rtl support.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity

Comment: I add my textview xml code. I want to set gravity for each line.

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think you can do it on a per line basis. You'll have to add N textviews 1 for each line.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
           if (textview.contentEquals("persian")) {
                textview.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            } else if (textview.contentEquals("english")) {
                textview.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            }
```

Comment: I want to set gravity for each line, not to set gravity for textview.

Comment: then set gravity to your layout or view, its a same process as textview.

Comment: suppose your linear layout have 3 line with 3 textview, then just set layout.setGravity(Gravity.start);

Comment: I have one text view and a dynamic large string that contains English and Persian. if I had a static string, I could use your suggestion. @Sagar Chavada

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic or static string

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try to use spannable and the Alignment properties:

Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE (right) and Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL (left).

Check this answer: [Multiple alignment in TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654022/multiple-alignment-in-textview)